# Generate custom error at compile time for safety checks

Tags: android

In my app there are many screens , and each screen has distinct screenIds. There are many developers too, contributing the app. I have faced a issue many times that developers forget to attach screen id . There is a method in base activity where we have to assign screen id , i have made that method abstract but people forget to write in it , leaving it empty . Is there a way through which it can be ensured that every screen (Activity here) gets a screenId if the abstract method is empty there will be compile time error or at min there will be a error in apk generation. Thanks for time .

Answer (score 0):

You may need to go through [Lint checks](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks), as Lint will scan your codebase all the time for the correctness in the code, If you make the correct use of it, you can break the build if code doesn't meet the requirement.